# Check if switches are started in mininet and resume script

Tags: shell, mininet, sdn, openvswitch

I have a linux bash script in which I create a mininet topology in a detached screen session. I want to pause the script and check if all the OVS switches in the mininet topology have started. If they have started, I will resume the script. How to check if the switches have started? I tried to assign the output like this if I have 20 switches:

```
x=`sudo ovs-ofctl show s20`
```

But the output is not assigned to "x" if there is no switch. I wanted to do this so I could compare it with the string:

```
ovs-ofctl: s20 is not a bridge or a socket
```

So what could I do in this case.